# Best way of spriting icons

Tags: css, svg, sass, gulp, sprite

I'm creating an application from scratch using angular2, SCSS and gulp.
I want to create high quality and responsive icons.  Exploring the web I found the that there are 2 main techniques:
- image sprites
- fonts
- SVG sprites

As as far as I saw the way to go is SVG sprites, wich seems also to be very usefull also for accesibility.

Do you have experience on this? I'm thinking in automating the creating with gulp, with a folder of SVG's that creates a single sprite file and it's css file.

Basically I want to know:
- is this cross browser?
- can the svg sprites be responsive?
- after creating the SVG sprite, how is the best way of using it on the HTML?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: May be helpful for you to read this: https://css-tricks.com/svg-sprites-use-better-icon-fonts/

Comment: Great example! i read it and it makes sense. Also I applied the external sprite use: https://css-tricks.com/examples/svg-for-everybody/

Comment: Also... if someone uses this, should be using also: https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg4everybody